# Using jquery sortable lists with GWT

Tags: jquery, list, gwt, drag, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a GWT web app and would like to implement some jquery code for a sortable list similar to this one: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ but the actual implementation is a little more complex. It seems GWT doesn't have any native support for this sort of thing, that's why I'm trying to drop in some basic jquery code.

The issue is that it seems jquery events don't trigger from the dynamically generated list items in GWT. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

We use gwt-dnd for drag & drop and it's been very stable so far.

The demo closest to your needs: http://allen-sauer.com/com.allen_sauer.gwt.dnd.demo.DragDropDemo/DragDropDemo.html#InsertPanelExample

In general, I've found using other GWT libraries preferable to mixing jQuery & GWT.

Comment: Yes, I've found that jQuery and GWT don't really like to play nice together. It seems jQuery just isn't able to bind to the dynamic views GWT pushes out. I've decided that instead I'm just going to run some of the views in an iFrame and then use GWT to go into the iFrame and pull out data. I feel using iFrames allows me to control the scope of the different frameworks and keep them from stepping on each other's toes. I'm not really interested in hacking their DnD framework together when it's something I can do in jQuery with just a few lines of js.

Comment: Ok. Parting advice: Loading different views in iframes so you can use different libraries will end up seeming like more of a hack than using a mature GWT library.

Comment: Yeah, but every time I want to use a different javascript library with GWT I'll have to write a GWT wrapper for it and keep tweaking it to get it to work the specific way I need it to. It's quite annoying when you're trying to get multiple different js libraries to work together inside of GWT and nothing is working properly. This would solve that issue and make it easy for me to add other libraries in the future without having to write a GWT wrapper for them.

Answer (score 0):

eeewwhwh, do not use external js libraries ontop of gwt, this creates a mess of code running in your browser as well as alot of memory leaks.

if your looking for fancyness check out GXT, however its a bit slow for apps that have to process very large data arrays.

if you want to implement it yourself it would be a bit of work but definaly not impossible. You will need to make the objects hide and show dynamically when you click to select one. and then once one is toggled to selected you will need to dynamically change the absolute position of the object based on the location of the cursor. Once you got this going you can add a listener on the object container to look for when the mouse is over the container. From there you can grab the coordinates again and dynamically show the object bounding box so it pushes the objects around your draggable.

i would definately use the gwt-dnd library to handle most of this.